# Function Efficiency

Tags: solidity, contract-design, gas

Say I have a function that handles 4 cases via if statements. I could break that into 4 separate functions. The case for breaking it up is that each function call would use less gas. The case against this is that my contract is longer. Is there a good rule for when to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost always preferable to avoid cases and if blocks if possible. This is for code smell and readability. Keep it as simple as possible.

Also, a best practice is to fail early and fail hard. So ...

Avoid

```
function doEverything(args) ... {
  if(case1) ... {
  } else {
  } ...
}
```

Better

```
function doCase1() ... {
  require(case1IsAllowed);
  ...
}

function doCase2() ... {
  require(case2IsAllowed);
  ...
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The downside here is that many dapps have a dozen contracts, often many with lists of functions that then require you to go elsewhere, and it's very hard to see all the ways users can interact with the contract.

Comment: Indeed. It's important to push hard in the direction of simplification.